# Why my incoming request not hitting my node.js(express ) server?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a `node.js(express)` app in which i have defined all my `routes`, `controllers` and all that.

`customer.route.js`

```
const express = require('express'); 
const Controller = require('../controllers/customer.controller');
const { customerValidationRules, validate } = require('../middlewares/request- validator.middleware');

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/create').post(customerValidationRules, validate, Controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

my `index.js` file inside `routes` folder

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const responseUtil = require('../helpers/response.helper');
const customerR = require('../routes/customer.route');

const router = express.Router();


router.use(cors());

router.use('/customers', customerR);


/** Returned when requested api url not found **/
router.use((req, res) => responseUtil.sendNotFound(res));

module.exports = router;
```

And my `app.js(root file)`

```
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

app.use('/api/v1', routes);
```

Now when i am hitting my `api` via `postman` with this api url

```
http://localhost:3003/api/v1/customers/create
```

So it keeps going and none of my logs priting on the console it means that request is not coming to my server now. Can any one let  me know what'st he issue in it.

Answer (score 1):

Because routes in Express router are not chained.
If you have

```
app.use('/customers',customerRouter)
```

Then you have to in your customerRouter define the whole route:

```
router.post('/customers/create', yourPostStuff)
```

Comment: and what about prefix `/api/v1`? i want to place this `/api/v1` prefix to all route groups like `customers`

Comment: No prefixes, the route in any express router or middleware function is compared to the whole path.

Comment: you can do something like const prefix= 'api/v1' and in the route use it like router.post(\``${prefix}/customers`\`, customerRouter) the ` is a backtick not normal quote

Comment: i mean that i want to place `/api/v1` to all my route groups that's why i did this `app.use('/api/v1', routes);` in my `app.js` and then place `router.post('/customers/create', yourPostStuff)` and now i am getting `404` not found on console for this `/api/v1/customers/create` url